# Why can't I assign a value to the class member variable in a bool function that returns const? C++

Tags: c++

```
bool Car::isEnoughFuel(int miles) const
{
drivableMiles = fuelGauge.getCurrentFuel() * MPG; // Error here
bool status = true;

if (miles > drivableMiles)
    status = false;
return status;
}
```

Error: Expression must be a modifiable lvalue.

Comment: Because that is what `const` means? Why are you trying to modify the state of an object in this function?

Comment: `const` doesn't mean that this function returns a constant, it means that it **can operate on constant `this`**, so all members must not change in it, and it mustn't call any non-`const` function

Comment: Assuming that `drivableMiles`is a class member variable of `Car` you'll need to make it `mutable` when trying to change it from a `const` function`

Comment: Because I want to return that drivableMiles to use in my main funtion.

Comment: @Brian _"Because I want to return that drivableMiles to use in my main funtion."_ That doesn't primarily require your function to be `const`. You can use a copy instead of changing the member variable though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Declaring a member function with the `const` keyword specifies that the function is a "read-only" function that does not modify the object for which it is called. A constant member function cannot modify any non-static data members or call any member functions that aren't constant. ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07x6b05d.aspx))

In the line `drivableMiles = fuelGauge.getCurrentFuel() * MPG;` you are trying to modify the object `isEnoughFuel()` is called on. You probably don't want to have your function as `const`. However one work around would be to using copies instead.